# alias argument in hierarchy in system verilog

Tags: multidimensional-array, alias, system-verilog

Is there way to make this `alias` statement work , as `iob` is bidirectional we cannot use `assign` statement. out of all the available `iob` pins only specific pins are connected to ddr memory dq bus. the other way we are doing is `include iob.svh` during instantiation of child module below is the snippets of required and implemented

```
   module top(
      input [63:0] ddr_dq
    );
    localparam NUM_HB = 24;
    
    logic [NUM_HB-1:0][4-1:0][8-1:0] iob;
      alias iob[0][0][0] = ddr_dq[0];
    
     phy u_phy (
      . iob (iob)
     );
    endmodule
    
    module phy (
      inout [NUM_HB-1:0][4-1:0][8-1:0] iob
    );
    endmodule
```

this is the work around implemented, but to get a the location of pin at single glance above `alias` statement will be useful

```
module top(
  input [63:0] ddr_dq
);
localparam NUM_HB = 24;

logic [NUM_HB-1:0][4-1:0][8-1:0] iob;
  //alias iob[0][0][0] = ddr_dq[0];

 phy u_phy (
  `include iob.svh
 );
endmodule
```

Contents of `include iob.svh` file is captured below

```
.iob( {
         nc_iob_pin[0]
        ,ddr_dq[0]
        ,ddr_dq[1]
        ,ddr_dq[2]
        ,ddr_dq[3]
        ,ddr_dq[4]
        ,ddr_dq[5]
})
```

Comment: Your workaround code does not demonstrate your problem statement very well. I assume you want to arbitrarily pick some of the 768 bits of `iob` in module `phy ` to connect to some, but not all bits of `ddr_dq` in an arbitrary order? It might help to show a pin mapping table.

Comment: Yes that's the intention, as serge mentioned I should use nets for `alias` statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which problem you saw. Alias statements only work with 'nets', so declaring *iob* as just *logic*, meaning `var logic` prevents it from being compiled. I did modify your code to make it compilable:

```
parameter NUM_HB = 24;

module top(
      input [63:0] ddr_dq
    );
    
    wire logic [NUM_HB-1:0][4-1:0][8-1:0] iob; // 'logic' is optional here
      alias iob[0][0][0] = ddr_dq[0];
    
     phy u_phy (
      . iob (iob)
     );
endmodule
    
module phy (
      inout [NUM_HB-1:0][4-1:0][8-1:0] iob
    );
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks serge for helping me, alias meant for nets I forgot.